# LoginLoop / Failed Kernel/ Nvidia drivers/Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

^

ive got an acer nitro 5 with a Geforce gtx 1080 and it was delivered with endless OS.
I tried to run Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time now and i cant install any n-vidia drivers without having login loop.
ALso without nvidia, just with nouveau driver, i have glitches and lags when i start in kernel 4.13. 
when i start with kernel 4.4. and nouveau, its ok, but i cant play games and would like to be able to update my drivers.

When i have login loop, it shows something with "failed : kernel", but its so fast, i cant even read it xD.
I tried several solutions from the web since 2 days, all the command lines, (purge nvidia*, reinstall,) it all comes down to situation i have now.

kernel 4.4. + nouveau = smooth interface, no login loop

kernel 4.13 + nouveau = lag, "stacking" interface, no login loop

kernel 4.4 + nvidia = smooth interface, but login loop

kernel 4.13 +nvidia = total devastation.

is there maybe a command to make a picture of my system, so somebody whos into that can tell me what to do?

please help me ^.^

and thank je well!

rebecca