# Cannot log in "your session lasted only 10 seconds"

Tags: 16.04, login

When I tried to log in this morning I got an error...

> your session lasted only 10 seconds...

under view details (`~/.xsession-errors` file) it reads..

```
initctl: Unable to connect to UPstart: failed to connect to socket
 /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused syndaemon: no process found
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup....
localuser:jackie being added to access control list
```

Any way to fix this without reinstalling?

Comment: What were you doing on the system yesterday before logging off? Does this issue occur each time you log in now?

Comment: I uninstalled open arena . yes every time I log In. it takes me to the log in screen but not any further than that.

Comment: Possibly related: [Ubuntu 16.04 Login Loop After Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019430/ubuntu-16-04-login-loop-after-update/1019443)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's VirtualBox that is the problem. Fix:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox*
```

I also faced the same problem. I got the solution from the below thread. I solved it and my computer is working fine. Just remove and restart the computer. Good Luck.

Reference:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433644/linux-mint-18-3-cinnamon-cannot-start-a-session

Comment: I forgotten I had installed `virtualbox`, but that worked for me!

Comment: Good to hear it worked for you..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try your method if it happens again. Reinstalled everything from scratch prior to your post.